# Figure and subfigures titles should be left justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, titles, subcaption

Could you please give me some advice about this situation?
Thank you so much.

I would like to move all the titles to the left.

But if we want to draw the following figure with 2 subfigures then we have to use packages "caption" and "subcaption", but these two packages will not allow us to move all the figure titles to the left.

---

```
\documentclass[smallextended,referee,envcountsect]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{multicol,color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\parskip 5pt
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.31in}\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.2in}\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\def\disp{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\clip(-5.039786976492287,-4.976475903092999) rectangle (5.225636493163389,4.854891605900701);
\fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (-2.9782972019669014,-3.011675055168333) -- (3.0217027980330986,-3.011675055168333) -- (3.021702798033099,2.9883249448316658) -- (-2.9782972019669005,2.988324944831667) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (-2.9782972019669014,-3.011675055168333)-- (3.0217027980330986,-3.011675055168333);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (3.0217027980330986,-3.011675055168333)-- (3.021702798033099,2.9883249448316658);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (3.021702798033099,2.9883249448316658)-- (-2.9782972019669005,2.988324944831667);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (-2.9782972019669005,2.988324944831667)-- (-2.9782972019669014,-3.011675055168333);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff] (-2.9782972019669014,-3.011675055168333) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=ududff] (3.0217027980330986,-3.011675055168333) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (3.021702798033099,2.9883249448316658) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-2.9782972019669005,2.988324944831667) circle (2.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{-0.1in}
\caption{\bf This is a square.}
\label{picnew}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]
\clip(-10.437883908168581,-9.13468903671252) rectangle (10.578095056602637,9.583415234871898);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (0.,0.) circle (2.4cm);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.,0.) circle (2.0pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{-0.1in}
\caption{\bf This is a circle.}
\label{pic2a*}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\bf Geometry.}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, most likely, but you're loading `hyperref` ways too early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have more problems with your code:

- in preamble of your mwe you have some packages loaded twice
- document class `svjour3` load `graphicx`, so you not need to load them (twice!)
- `tikz` is not able to handle so accurate defined coordinates as you use. it is sufficient to round them to two decimals
- for your problem are relevant only the following packages: `tikz`, `subcaption` and `hyperref`.
- float environments should not be inside other environments like `center` or `minipage` ...
- for left align of caption and sub-captions use caption set up `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}`

**edit:**
mostly of topic ...

- your image code is really unnecessary complicated
- it is far more simple (to my experiences) for your geometric elements use shapes defined in `tikz` package (`rectangle`, circle`)
- for caption and sub-captions set up see documentations for `caption` and `subcaption` packages, both are part of your LaTeX installation
- definitions of your colors should be in document preamble
- changes in preamble are indicated by `% <---`

mwe, considering aforementioned, is:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,referee,envcountsect]{svjour3}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\smartqed
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5ex,           % <---
              font=bf,              % <---
              singlelinecheck=off}  % <---
\captionsetup{skip=0.5ex}           % <---
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0ex}  % <---
\def\disp{\displaystyle}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
\tikzset{% definiton of used styles
box/.style args = {#1/#2}{rectangle, draw=#1, fill=#1, minimum size=#2,
                          line width=2pt, fill opacity=0.1,
                          outer sep=0pt},
cir/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{circle, draw=#1, fill=#2, minimum size=#3,
                             line width=2pt},
dot/.style = {circle, draw, thin, fill=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt},
        }            
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (s) [box=zzttqq/45mm] {};
\foreach \i/\j in {north east/uuuuuu, north west/uuuuuu, 
                  south west/ududff, south east/ududff}
    \node [dot=\j] at (s.\i) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\bf This is a square.}
\label{picnew}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]
\node (s) [cir=black/white/45mm] {};%(2.4cm);
\node [dot=uuuuuu] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a circle.}
\label{pic2a*}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Geometry.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help. Could you please let me know how can you make "(a)", "(b)" and "Fig. 1" in bold? I just know how to make the sentences "This is a square" in bold by command {\bf ...}.

Comment: @Ross, later evening (CET) now i'm on the way.

Comment: Please take your time. Thank you very much, Zarko.

Comment: I found it \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}. Thank you again. ^^

Comment: @Ross, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, Zarko. May I ask you one more question? "Typically, manuscripts should be typed on 8.5in by 11in pages with a 1.0in margin all around with a font size of 10 pt." So if I want to do it, then I should change "\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}"? Is that correct? Thank you.

Comment: @Ross, you are right. size of page is determined by document class (`svjour3`), however you can say `a4paper` or `letterpaper` or select others size. for details about `geometry` package see documentation for this package. it is part of its installation.  docement also load default (desired) font size.